# How well should you know electromagnetism before studying Antenna Theory

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, wave

There are 3 main books in electromagnetism from "easy" to "hard": Griffiths, Purcell and then Jackson's. I will start the study of Antennas in the next week. However, I'm a bit worried because even though I got a decent understand of Maxwell's equations, I didnt get to study electromagnetic waves. How in depth should I go to be prepared for Antenna Theory by Balanis?

EDIT: Found a good alternative. Sadiku's Elements of Electromagnetics. I've had a good time with Sadiku's book on circuit analysis so I'm a bit biased. However, his treatment of EM waves seems to be geared towards engineering, contrary to the other books mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read the book from Balanis, so I can't say for sure at which level of depth it treats antennas (i.e., does it cover antenna design?).

Anyway, not knowing anything about wave propagation will hamper your understanding severely. Knowing Maxwell's equations (MEs) is just the starting point.

In particular, MEs is the basis for understanding transmission lines and then waveguides. Antennas are useless if you don't know how to convey a signal to/from them, and for that you need transmission lines and/or waveguides.

Moreover, antenna theory heavily involves wave propagation in free space, so if you didn't study wave theory, you'll be in trouble, unless the course you are going to follow focuses on mere qualitative analysis.

See [the relevant article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_(radio)), for example. It is almost entirely qualitative, and touches an incredible range of subjects.

Every one of that subjects can be developed quantitatively, and the theory can be quite complex.

Anyway, it seems you are following a college/university course, hence the best advice is *ask your teacher* or a student tutor (if they exist in your university system), or even students that already followed the course you are going to follow.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to know. Communications is a massive subject. Electromagnetic theory basics are straightforward to understand.

As for its contribution to designing antennas, you need very little electromagnetic theory. Electromagnetic theory deals with field/wave direction amplitudes, velocity, transmission and reflection of mediums, ect. Its all the about the wave itself.

When designing antennas, it is a lot more straight to point. For example, radiating power from antenna = input power - feeder loss + gain. This is because a theory is prominently free-space so you ignore effects like dispersion ect. It will look more into the actual antenna itself, like lengths, directivity, sensitivity, maximum free space communication range ect. The deeper you go into the subject, the more they will intertwine, but for an introduction, there is not alot of crossover.